# How felix console uses metatype.xml file

Tags: osgi, apache-felix

I want to understand the use of metatype for component.

I understand, if we keep it true than it will generate `OSGI-INF/metatype/metatype.xml` else it would not. Also, I'm well aware that keeping the value of attribute true will show it in Apache Felix Console, editing it will create a corresponding config save in /apps/system/config and deleting that will again bring config state in Felix console to default.

Quoting from [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34874370/usecase-of-metatype-attribute-in-felix-scr-annotations) question's accepted answer, `

> **How Metatype data can be used** by administrative systems or GUIs such
>   as Felix Web Console to present a much more helpful way to configure
>   your component?
>   and **what is the concept of binding** with bundle in terms of this
>   configuration?

`

Comment: What is your actual question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this service : https://osgi.org/javadoc/r6/cmpn/org/osgi/service/metatype/MetaTypeService.html

With the MetaTypeService, you can dynamically instropect a bundle and discovers metatype information about his configuration, with type, description, etc.

The Felix WebConsole use this metatype information to show a UI more "userfriendly" for the configuration of a composant.